# How to connect Devise to current Volunteers table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm trying to find the best way to associate some of my volunteers in a volunteers table as admin users that can log into the system.

I am using Devise and Rails.

Originally I just added Devise to the existing Volunteer table, but that is definitely not the best solution as most volunteers won't be allowed to login anyway, and I would have to create a password for each volunteer I add.

One option is to create a separate admin table, but then admins will have to manage both their admin email and volunteer email separately (admins are also volunteers).

Is there a way to associate the volunteers table to an admin's table?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to put the email in the volunteers table and have the admin model delegate to it. That is no email field in the admins table. Something like:

admin.rb

```
belongs_to :volunteer
delegate :email, :email=, :to => volunteer
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about delegate. What would be the best solution to actually connect them, and how would I connect them?

Would I create a checkbox in my create volunteer form that saves the id from the admin table? Would I use STI or a polymorphic relationship instead? Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add a volunteer_id foreign key in the admins table and add `has_one :admin` to the Volunteer model and that's pretty much it. `current_admin.volunteer` will return the volunteer associated to the current user (or current_admin if that's how you configure it). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I added the foreign key, and the appropriate relationships in the model. I'm still relatively new to rails, so I'm still confused how I go about creating a new volunteer, and then setting them as an admin in the same creation form. 

Or do I have to create the volunteer and admin records separately, and the admin's would have to edit 2 separate accounts? Their admin account, and their volunteer account?

Comment: How do you intend to create admin accounts? Will you allow users to register or maybe from your admin dashboard you want to select a volunteer and make it an admin? Another way to put it is; what is created first, the volunteer or the admin?

Comment: It would be best to choose them as an admin upon creating their entry, but if that's too complicated, then create the volunteer first, then change them to an admin. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: You have several options. I would have a 'make this volunteer an admin' checkbox. If that's selected in your VolunteersController#create do something like `@volunteer.create_admin(:password => 'xxx', :password_confirmation => 'xxx'` (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference). You have to deal with side issues such as letting your volunteers know what password you set up for them.